# How to suppress output in imported module

Tags: python, numpy, output

I have a module with one method:

```
def find_inverse_matrix(C, log=False): 

    n = C.shape[0]

    Cs = C.copy()
    i = 0
    C = np.matrix(np.eye(n))
    B = np.matrix(np.eye(n))
    J = set(range(n))
    S = [0] * n

    if log: print Cs

    while i <= n-1:
        if log: print '\nIteration', i
        f = False
        j = 0
        ei = get_ek(i, n)

        for j in J:
            cj = get_ck(Cs, j)
            alpha = (ei * B * cj)[0, 0]
            if log: print 'alpha%s = %s' % (j, alpha)
            if not(is_zero(alpha)):
                f = True
                break

        if not(f):
            exit('Inverse matrix is not exist')

        J.remove(j)
        S[j] = i
        C[:, i] = Cs[:, j]
        if log: print 'C%s:\n%s' % (i, C)
        D = get_Dkz(i, B * C[:, i])
        if log: print 'D%s:\n%s' % (i, D)
        B = D * B
        if log: print 'B%s:\n%s' % (i, B)

        i += 1
    if log: print '\n S = ', S

    if log: print 'Result'
    R = construct_matrix(B, S)
    if log: print R

    if log: print '\nCheck result:'
    if log: print Cs * R
    return R
```

If I call this method from this file it shows all print, but if I call if from another all print should be suppressed. Now I use check before every print, but how it do simple and pretty in 'pythonic' style?

Comment: [Python » Documentation » Python HOWTOs » Logging HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

Comment: Thank for your advance. I know about logging module, but at present the module already written with 'print' statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `print` is a statement in the language. But if you add the line `from __future__ import print_function` to your imports then it is used as a function. This means two things:

a) You need to use this as a function - meaning `print(Cs)` instead of `print Cs`.

b) You can override it, since in python functions are objects you can play with.

You can define your own "my_print" functions which you can later change instead of the builtin `print`.

Example:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> _print_ = print
>>> def myprint(*arg, **kwarg):
...     _print_("yeah.")
...     _print_(*arg,** kwarg)
...
>>> myprint("ok")
yeah.
ok
>>> print = myprint
>>> print('3')
yeah.
3
>>>
```

So just write your `myprint` function so that it'd check for "log" before, and your prints should be the same. Or just override `print` only when you don't want to suppress printing.

Comment: In this case I need to modify only imported module, right? See example https://dpaste.de/HPHdw/

Comment: The output is at the bottom? Then it gave you the desired result, right?

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__ == '__main__':` will execute a block of code only if a file is executed directly, not loaded as a module. You can set a flag there to turn on logging.

A more pythonic way might be to pass a log function into the module instead of a flag. That way you could pass in an empty function to suppress logging.